# How to filter by User's Email in GQL from property type User in Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, developer-console

One entity named Account has a User type property as the following:

**Account**
AccountName *String*
Owner *User*
....

In App Engine Data Store Viewer, I can filter by email by using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Account where owner = User('example@gmail.com')
```

Using the same query in the new Google Developer Console Datastore Query, I get the following error:
"Unknown function "User"."

The property owner looks like the following in the Developer Console:

{"properties":{"auth_domain":{"stringValue":"gmail.com","indexed":false},"email":{"stringValue":"example@gmail.com","indexed":false},"user_id":{"stringValue":"5555555555555555555","indexed":false}}}

The owner entity of type User is not indexed.
What is the equivalent GQL query I can use in the new Google Developer Console?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey! I don't remember if the old console COULD to that (I didn't use it enough), but if you have print screens of both the old console working and the new console not working, I would suggest posting this on our Issue Tracker here : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: Hi! I added the screenshots above. @Patrice is there a way to filter by email on the new console? I will post it in the Google issues as well.

Comment: Since it's not indexed, I don't think there's a way.... I'll check out to see if there's a viable workaround :)